# How to resolve bottom overflowed by infinity pixels?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make a Flutter app that can respond to a tap anywhere on the screen, using a `GestureDetector`. Here's my code:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "App",
      home: MyScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => MyScreenState();
}

class MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {
  String _text = "Hello";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _onTapUp(TapUpDetails details) {
      var x = details.globalPosition.dx;
      var y = details.globalPosition.dy;
      print("tap up " + x.toString() + ", " + y.toString());

      setState(() {
        _text = "Hello world";
      });
    }

    return GestureDetector(
      onTapUp: _onTapUp,
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("App")
          ),
          body: Text(_text),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However, when I run the app an error appears on the bottom of the simulator saying `BOTTOM OVERFLOWED BY Infinity PIXELS`. The app appears to be functioning, but the error at the bottom is an eyesore. How can I resolve it?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I copy pasted your code, and I don't get any overflow.

Comment: @Darky my mistake - the code wasn't totally up-to-date. It's been difficult to debug this error, though, because it appears intermittently and it takes several rounds of rebuilding/re-running to get the app running on the simulator to actually update.

Comment: I had a similar problem (yet not with infinity pixels). I ended up here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49614547/5766375 and used this solution, I wrapped my column with a SingleChildScrollView.

Comment: maybe you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53809904/6224209) :)

Comment: I have tried your code and it seems working fine. Everything I tap into the screen returns the `x` and `y` coordinate correctly. If ever you got a chance, could you provide a screenshot and at least highlight the area in the screen where you get that error?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be unreproducible. The `child` widget defined on `GestureDetector` should set its height and prevent pixel overflows.

But if you need to define the height of your screen to avoid bottom overflows, you can either use [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) or [MediaQuery](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html) to fetch the screen dimensions.