# Flutter (Dart): Exceptions caused by rendering / A RenderFlex overflowed

Tags: mobile, dart, rendering, overflow, flutter

I have a problem with Flutter (Dart) RenderFlex overflowed pixels. An exception of rendering library.

How can I manage or apply scrolling ability to my app page view and avoid Flutter's rendering exceptions with messages like:

> A RenderFlex overflowed by 28 pixels on the bottom.

if you by any chance need the full log to help me is here:

[image]

on the hot-reload it comes up with the yellow/black stripes at the bottom as per the message.

Is this something I can manage with a scrollable widget? Or I can declare otherwise my widgets in order to control it?

full code if needed (i changed the Text data but assume the texts appearing are longer than the screen size, and thus the error comes up):

```
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            bottom: new TabBar(
              tabs: [
                new Tab(text: "xxx",),
                new Tab(text: "xxx",),
                new Tab(text: "xxx",),
              ],
            ),
            title: new Text(data["xxx"]),
          ),
          body: new TabBarView(
            children: [
              new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Text(data["xxx"],
                        style: new TextStyle(
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              fontSize: 16.0
                        ),),
                  new Text(data["xxx"],
                        style: new TextStyle(
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              fontSize: 10.0
                        ),),
                  new Text(data["xxx"],
                        style: new TextStyle(
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              fontSize: 16.0
                        ),),
                  new Text(data["xxx"],
                        style: new TextStyle(
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              fontSize: 8.0
                        ),
                      ),
                  new Text(data["xxx"],
                        style: new TextStyle(
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              fontSize: 8.0
                        ),),

                  new Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Expanded(
                        child: new Text("xxx"),
                      ),
                      new Expanded(
                        child: new Icon(Icons.file_download, color: Colors.green, size: 30.0,),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),

                  new Divider(),
                  new Text("xxx", 
                            style: new TextStyle(
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              color: Colors.red,
                              fontSize: 16.0
                      ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),

              new ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => new EntryItem(_lstTiles[index]),
                itemCount: _lstTiles.length,
              ),

              new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Text(data["xxx"], 
                            style: new TextStyle(
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              color: Colors.green[900],
                              fontSize: 16.0
                      ),
                  ),
                  new Text(data["xxx"], 
                            style: new TextStyle(
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              color: Colors.green[900],
                              fontSize: 16.0
                      ),),
                  new Text(data["xxx"]),
                  new ListTile(title: new Text("xxx")),
                  new Text(data["xxx"]),
                  new ListTile(title: new Text("xxx")),
                  new Divider(),
                  new Text("xxx", 
                            style: new TextStyle(
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              color: Colors.red,
                              fontSize: 16.0
                      ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
```

Comment: You can put one of the scrollable widgets around your content to allow it to scroll and prevent the error.

Comment: hi Herohtar, yes indeed...today I was resolving the issue through https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html in order to provide the scrolling functionality needed

Answer (score 180, accepted):

This is a pretty common issue to run into, especially when you start testing your app on multiple devices and orientations. Flutter's Widget gallery has a section covering the various scrolling widgets:

https://flutter.io/widgets/scrolling/

I'd recommend either wrapping your entire content in a [`SingleChildScrollView`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html), or using a scrolling [`ListView`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html).

**EDIT:** This question and answer have gotten some notice, so I'd like to provide a little more help for those who land here.

The Flutter SDK team puts a lot of effort into good documentation within the SDK code itself. One of the best resources for understanding the algorithm that `Flex` widgets (`Row` and `Column` are both subclasses of `Flex`) use to lay out their children is the DartDoc that accompanies the class itself:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/e3005e6962cfefbc12e7aac56576597177cc966f/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart#L3724

The Flutter website also contains a [tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout) on building layouts and an [interactive codelab](https://flutter.dev/docs/codelabs/layout-basics) about how to use `Row` and `Column` widgets.

Comment: And what if you don't want it to scroll? In my case, I have a Card > ScopedModelDescendant > Column > Container. I don't want the column to scroll, but the Containers overflow it. Any ideas?

Comment: First, I'd try setting the Column's crossAxisAlignment value to `stretch` or wrapping the Container in an Expanded widget. This will try and force it to be the correct size. If that doesn't work, you'd need to look at the children of the container and determine which one is preventing it from being the correct size. You can also try a FittedBox, which can scale/clip contents in order to make them fit.

Comment: @forresthopkinsa to prevent scrolling use `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` in a `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: @Curly Thanks, but my question already got answered. Didn't need a ScrollView at all.

Comment: @forresthopkinsa could you please share the solution? I am facing the same issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: SingleChildScrollView works. Btw, you rock on YouTube!

Comment: If you have a simple layout with a single column that needs to scroll and you are facing this issue, you can wrap your column with a `SingleChildScrollView`. Thanks for the answer (Y)

Comment: I am using listview.builder and getting the error (and finding this).. but perhaps because there is a data entry Textfield() before the FutureBuilder -- listview... wrapping the listview did not work, but wrapping the column did work..

Answer (score 51):

Let's say you have a `List` of 100 `Text` widgets like this:

```
final children = List<Widget>.generate(100, (i) => Text('Item $i')).toList();
```

Depending on the device screen, these widgets can overflow, there are few solutions to handle it.

1. Use `Column` wrapped in `SingleChildScrollView`

   ```
   SingleChildScrollView(
     child: Column(children: children),
   )
   ```
2. Use `ListView`

   ```
   ListView(
     children: children
   )
   ```
3. Use combination of both `Column` and `ListView`(you should use `Expanded`/`Flexible`, or give a fixed height to the `ListView` when doing so).

   ```
   Column(
     children: [
       ...children.take(2).toList(), // show first 2 children in Column
       Expanded(
         child: ListView(
           children: children.getRange(3, children.length).toList(),
         ), // And rest of them in ListView
       ),
     ],
   )
   ```

Comment: `body: SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(children: children),
)` solved the issue of A RenderFlex overflowed by 161 pixels on the bottom.

Comment: Expanded widget works for me :)

Answer (score 16):

I was also facing this issue, try this ....

```
resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
```

Before the body part

**EDIT - 1**

`resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` is deprecated

```
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false
```

Comment: This only applies to situations, where you do not want to scroll. Also next time please provide more information, to put this line of code into the scaffold widget.

Comment: Update: resizeToAvoidBottomPadding is deprecated. 
Use resizeToAvoidBottomInset : false

Answer (score 3):

I you are using column, wrap you inner-widget with expanded like this

```
 Expanded( 
        child: Center(
          child: Image(
            image: AssetImage('assets/icons/${menuItem.iconData}'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the widget `Expanded` for each container inside the column. And then use `flex` to make the correct adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the Column with a SingleChildScrollView.

Answer (score 1):

If Column is failing you, try [Wrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html):

```
// doesn't pass unit tests
return Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Icon(
      icon ?? Icons.cancel_outlined,
      size: 64.0,
      color: theme.colorScheme.error,
    ),
    Text(
      errorTitle,
      style: theme.textTheme.displayLarge,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
    Text(
      errorDetails,
      style: theme.textTheme.titleLarge,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
    if (onPressedActionButton != null && textActionButton != null)
      ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: onPressedActionButton,
        child: Text(textActionButton!),
      ),
  ],
);

// passes unit tests
return Wrap(
  direction: Axis.horizontal,
  alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
  runSpacing: 32,
  children: [
    Icon(
      icon ?? Icons.cancel_outlined,
      size: 64.0,
      color: theme.colorScheme.error,
    ),
    Text(
      errorTitle,
      style: theme.textTheme.displayLarge,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
    Text(
      errorDetails,
      style: theme.textTheme.titleLarge,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
    if (onPressedActionButton != null && textActionButton != null)
      ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: onPressedActionButton,
        child: Text(textActionButton!),
      ),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the text in **PreferredSize** widget:

```
 bottom: PreferredSize(
                    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(120.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              right: 5.0, left: 5.0, bottom: 2.0, top: 2.0),
                          child: Text(
                            hospitalName,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 14.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 1.0,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 2.0, right: 5.0, left: 5.0, bottom: 2.0),
                          child: Text(
                            doctorName,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 14.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 1.0,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
            
                        TabBar(
                          isScrollable: true,
                          tabs: [
                            Tab(
                              text: "Tab1",
                            ),
                            Tab(text: "Tab2"),
                            Tab(text: "Tab3"),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    )),
```

Comment: In some cases adjusting the Size.fromHeight(120.0) fixes the rendering issue

Answer (score 0):

For me, I added a text to one of row children, i was fetching data from firebase and it was null. So make sure there is some data coming.

Answer (score 0):

when increasing text size without wanting to expand widget size use **FittedBox** for perfect fit

for example

```
      Text(
          'Unread: $notificationCount',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.red),
        ),

        //u can do this wrap the widget with the FittedBox
   FittedBox(
          fit: BoxFit.scaleDown, //adjust BoxFit property according to your will
          child: Text(
            'Unread: $notificationCount',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.red),
          ),
        ),
```