# Flutter: A RenderFlex overflowed by 33 pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter

I got error debugging my flutter application on android.

The error is : A RenderFlex overflowed by 33 pixels on the bottom.

Looks like my virtual Android device screen cannot handle Container or Expanded Widget? I am not sure though.

Here's my code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:material_design_icons_flutter/material_design_icons_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:barcode_scan/barcode_scan.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(
  MaterialApp(home: BallPage()),
);

class BallPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BallPageState createState() => _BallPageState();
}

class _BallPageState extends State<BallPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      drawer: new Drawer(
            child: ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              children: <Widget>[
                DrawerHeader(
                  child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                    Positioned(
                        bottom: 12.0,
                        left: 16.0,
                        child: Text("My Magic Numbers",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 20.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))),
                  ]),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.center_focus_strong),
                  title: Text('QR Scan'),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()));
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.map),
                  title: Text('Winners Map'),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => GMapRoute()));
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Magic 6 balls'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        actions: <Widget>[
          /*new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(MdiIcons.squareInc),
            color: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()));
            },
          ), */
        ],
      ),
      body: Number()
    );
  }
}


class GMapRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<GMapRoute> createState() => GMapRouteState();
}

class GMapRouteState extends State<GMapRoute> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          ),
          title: Text('Winners Map'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body: GoogleMap(
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: LatLng(40.688841, -74.044015),
            zoom: 11,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    );
  }
}


class SecondRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondRouteState createState() {
    return new _SecondRouteState();
  }
}

class _SecondRouteState extends State<SecondRoute> {
  String result = "Hey there!";

  Future _scanQR() async {
    try {
      String qrResult = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
      setState(() {
        result = qrResult;
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (ex) {
      if (ex.code == BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied) {
        setState(() {
          result = "Camera permission was denied";
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          result = "Unknown Error $ex";
        });
      }
    } on FormatException {
      setState(() {
        result = "You pressed the black button before scanning anything";
      });
    } catch (ex) {
      setState(() {
        result = "Unknown Error $ex";
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: new IconButton(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        ),
        title: Text('QR Code Scan'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          result,
          style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: _scanQR,
        label: Text('Scan'),
        icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }
}

class Number extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NumberState createState() => _NumberState();
}

class _NumberState extends State<Number> {
  List<List<int>> items= [
//    [1+ Random().nextInt(49), 1 + Random().nextInt(49), 1, 1, 1, 1]
  ];

  String generateString() {
    var items = List.generate(50, (index) => index + 1)..shuffle();
    return items.take(6).join(' ');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                new Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 150.0),
                  child: new Text(
                    'Winners Number',
                    style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: items.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      height: 60,
                      width: 60,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                          Container(
                            height: 60,
                            width: 60,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '${items[index][0]}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 60,
                            width: 60,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '${items[index][1]}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 60,
                            width: 60,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '${items[index][2]}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 60,
                            width: 60,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '${items[index][3]}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 60,
                            width: 60,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '${items[index][4]}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 60,
                            width: 60,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '${items[index][5]}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: new Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 130.0),
                child: RaisedButton.icon(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                  label: Text('Add Rows'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      if (items.length < 6) {
                        items.add([
                          1 + Random().nextInt(49),
                          1 + Random().nextInt(49),
                          1 + Random().nextInt(49),
                          1 + Random().nextInt(49),
                          1 + Random().nextInt(49),
                          1 + Random().nextInt(49)
                        ]);
                        // print(items[0]);
                      }
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10.0),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 130.0),
                child: RaisedButton.icon(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
                  label: Text('Remove Rows'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      items.removeLast();
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          ),
        ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            //            items.forEach((x) {
            //              x = [
            //                1 + Random().nextInt(49),
            //                1 + Random().nextInt(49),
            //                1 + Random().nextInt(49),
            //                1 + Random().nextInt(49),
            //                1 + Random().nextInt(49),
            //                1 + Random().nextInt(49)
            //              ];
            //              print(x);
            //            });
            //
            if (items.length == 1 ) {
              items[0] = List.generate(50, (index) => index + 1)..shuffle();
            } else if (items.length == 2) {
              items[0] = List.generate(50, (index) => index + 1)..shuffle();
              items[1] = List.generate(50, (index) => index + 1)..shuffle();
            } else if (items.length == 3) {
              items[0] = List.generate(50, (index) => index + 1)..shuffle();
              items[1] = List.generate(50, (index) => index + 1)..shuffle();
              items[2] = List.generate(50, (index) => index + 1)..shuffle();
            } else if (items.length == 4) {
              items[0] = List.generate(50, (index) => index + 1)..shuffle();
              items[1] = List.generate(50, (index) => index + 1)..shuffle();
              items[2] = List.generate(50, (index) => index + 1)..shuffle();
              items[3] = List.generate(50, (index) => index + 1)..shuffle();
            } else if (items.length == 5) {
              items[0] = List.generate(50, (index) => index + 1)..shuffle();
              items[1] = List.generate(50, (index) => index + 1)..shuffle();
              items[2] = List.generate(50, (index) => index + 1)..shuffle();
              items[3] = List.generate(50, (index) => index + 1)..shuffle();
              items[4] = List.generate(50, (index) => index + 1)..shuffle();
            } else {
              items[0] = List.generate(50, (index) => index + 1)..shuffle();
              items[1] = List.generate(50, (index) => index + 1)..shuffle();
              items[2] = List.generate(50, (index) => index + 1)..shuffle();
              items[3] = List.generate(50, (index) => index + 1)..shuffle();
              items[4] = List.generate(50, (index) => index + 1)..shuffle();
              items[5] = List.generate(50, (index) => index + 1)..shuffle();
            }
          });

        },
        label: Text('Click Here!'),
        icon: Icon(Icons.loop),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the error from the console:

```
I/flutter (23120): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (23120): The following assertion was thrown during layout:
I/flutter (23120): A RenderFlex overflowed by 33 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter (23120): 
I/flutter (23120): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter (23120):   Column file:///Users/minkyeong/AndroidStudioProjects/magic-8-ball-flutter/lib/main.dart:198:24
I/flutter (23120): 
I/flutter (23120): The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
I/flutter (23120): The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and
I/flutter (23120): black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
I/flutter (23120): Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the
I/flutter (23120): RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
I/flutter (23120): This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
I/flutter (23120): seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a
I/flutter (23120): ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex,
I/flutter (23120): like a ListView.
I/flutter (23120): The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#0f551 relayoutBoundary=up6 OVERFLOWING:
I/flutter (23120):   creator: Column ← Expanded ← Column ← Center ← _BodyBuilder ← MediaQuery ←
I/flutter (23120):     LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.body>] ← CustomMultiChildLayout ← AnimatedBuilder ← DefaultTextStyle ←
I/flutter (23120):     AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ← _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#fea7c ink renderer] ← ⋯
I/flutter (23120):   parentData: offset=Offset(105.5, 0.0); flex=1; fit=FlexFit.tight (can use size)
I/flutter (23120):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=360.0, h=140.0)
I/flutter (23120):   size: Size(149.0, 140.0)
I/flutter (23120):   direction: vertical
I/flutter (23120):   mainAxisAlignment: start
I/flutter (23120):   mainAxisSize: max
I/flutter (23120):   crossAxisAlignment: center
I/flutter (23120):   verticalDirection: down
I/flutter (23120): ◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
I/flutter (23120): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Can anyone fix this error? I have no idea why only Android gets the error while IOS device does not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter (Dart): Exceptions caused by rendering / A RenderFlex overflowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49480051/flutter-dart-exceptions-caused-by-rendering-a-renderflex-overflowed)

Comment: The problem is in the size of the Widget (maybe Image or anything)use Expanded instead of Container or Smaller image

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to check the issue locally with some minimal code from your example.

Inside the `Column` there are 3 `Expanded` children which suppose to share the space. On my understanding, those 3 children should share the available space according to the [`flex`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible/flex.html) factor.

> If null or zero, the child is inflexible and determines its own size.
> If non-zero, the amount of space the child's can occupy in the main
> axis is determined by dividing the free space (after placing the
> inflexible children) according to the flex factors of the flexible
> children.

I've noticed that the `flex` factor of one of the children is set to 2 and it seems that it is taking much more than any available space which causes the other children to overflow.

```
Expanded(
       // This is where the issue is occurring.
            flex: 2,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: items.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      height: 60,
                      width: 60,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                          Container(
                            height: 60,
                            width: 60,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '${items[index][0]}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 60,
                            width: 60,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '${items[index][1]}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 60,
                            width: 60,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '${items[index][2]}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 60,
                            width: 60,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '${items[index][3]}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 60,
                            width: 60,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '${items[index][4]}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 60,
                            width: 60,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '${items[index][5]}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
            ),
          ),
```

It will result to this:

[image]

Refactoring the minimal code by setting all the `flex` factor of children to 1 to fit in the remaining space:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<List<int>> items = [
//    [1+ Random().nextInt(49), 1 + Random().nextInt(49), 1, 1, 1, 1]
  ];

  String generateString() {
    var items = List.generate(50, (index) => index + 1)..shuffle();
    return items.take(6).join(' ');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: new Column(
                children: [
                  new Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 150.0),
                    child: new Text(
                      'Winners Number',
                      style: new TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: items.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      height: 60,
                      width: 60,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                          Container(
                            height: 60,
                            width: 60,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '${items[index][0]}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 60,
                            width: 60,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '${items[index][1]}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 60,
                            width: 60,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '${items[index][2]}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 60,
                            width: 60,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '${items[index][3]}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 60,
                            width: 60,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '${items[index][4]}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 60,
                            width: 60,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '${items[index][5]}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 130.0),
                    child: RaisedButton.icon(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                      label: Text('Add Rows'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (items.length < 6) {
                            items.add([
                              1 + Random().nextInt(49),
                              1 + Random().nextInt(49),
                              1 + Random().nextInt(49),
                              1 + Random().nextInt(49),
                              1 + Random().nextInt(49),
                              1 + Random().nextInt(49)
                            ]);
                            // print(items[0]);
                          }
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 130.0),
                    child: RaisedButton.icon(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
                      label: Text('Remove Rows'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          items.removeLast();
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This should fix the issue:

[image]

See more about Expanded [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html).