# Flutter - Image have overflow despite the defined width?

Tags: flutter, dart, overflow

Is my network image still overflowing, despite the defined width, and why?

Here is a problematic part of the code:

```
Container(
  height: 200,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, // This may be helpful, but not in my case...
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
      image: NetworkImage("${module['thumbnail']}"),
      ),
   ),
),
```

How to fix overflow?

```
A RenderFlex overflowed by 28 pixels on the right.
```

Help, I am a newbie in Flutter. Thanks!

Ps. Updated code from top to problematic :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SingleModule()),
          );
        },
        child: Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
          ),
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 200,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        image: NetworkImage("${module['thumbnail']}"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: can you add the image URL for `module['thumbnail']` eg: https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1628267374795-cce89ff4b8d1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=983&q=80

Comment: Hi @DineshNagarajan, I am not sure am I understand you? 
What do you mean? In that variable is the network URL. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49614547/2804581

Comment: @Nagual, done! :)

Comment: @Nagual, I have replaced the row with ``Expanded`` and it's work! Not more overflow, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 28),` to your `Container` that wrap around your `Image Widget`.