# Flutter widget not rendering on the screen. I am getting the following error : "A RenderFlex overflowed by Infinity pixels on the bottom."

Tags: flutter

I am working on a flutter app.
The widgets are not rendering on the screen.
Here's the problamatic code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Let's get productive!"),
        ),
        body: Material(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Pomodoro(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: 'Home',
              //backgroundColor:
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.analytics),
              label: 'Home',
              //backgroundColor:
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              label: 'Home',
              //backgroundColor:
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`The Pomodoro class`

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [Color(0xff1542bf), Color(0xff51a8ff)],
            begin: FractionalOffset(0.5, 1),
          ),
        ),
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              child: Text(
                "Pomodoro",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 30.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: CircularPercentIndicator(
                radius: 250.0,
                percent: percent,
                animation: true,
                animateFromLastPercent: true,
                lineWidth: 20.0,
                progressColor: Colors.white,
                backgroundWidth: 50.0,
                center: Text(
                  "$timeInMinute",
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 80.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried changing the height and width of the container, removing the scaffold and just returning the container, and removing the container just keeping the column in the scaffold body and removing the expanded widget. No matter what I do, I get the same error. Kindly help me.

Also, I do not want to make the home screen scrollable. I want everything to fit inside the screen and also be responsive to different screen sizes. I tried media queries to give size but that too didn't work.

[Here's the link to the github repo for the app:](https://github.com/Rachita-Dongre/productivityplus)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter (Dart): Exceptions caused by rendering / A RenderFlex overflowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49480051/flutter-dart-exceptions-caused-by-rendering-a-renderflex-overflowed)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code.

1. The error is saying your widget is overflowing on the bottom, so you need to make your page scrollable. You can change your column to a `ListView` instead:

   ```
          child: Material(
            child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: [
                Pomodoro(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
   ```
2. Your container in `Pomodoro()` doesn't have a height parameter, which is causing renderbox issues.

   ```
      Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(...),
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 500.0, //add a height
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added the height to the container and that solved the background color problem. However the main problem still persists. The circular percent indicator is still overflowing. Also I do not want to make the screen scrollable. So adding listview in the homepage might not work for me.

Comment: oh ok. Are you able to provide a screenshot of how your simulator is displayed? because im not seeing any error on my end. Is your Pomodoro a stateless or stateful widget?  Also, add this to your columns: mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove some widgets to make your above code work.

Firstly, remove the Scaffold widget from Pomodoro class.
Lastly, remove the Expanded Widget from your CircularPercentIndicator. It will fix your error. Check below code for Pomodoro class.

```
return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [Color(0xff1542bf), Color(0xff51a8ff)],
          begin: FractionalOffset(0.5, 1),
        ),
      ),
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: Text(
              "Pomodoro",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 30.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20.0,
          ),
          CircularPercentIndicator(
            radius: 250.0,
            percent: 0.8,
            animation: true,
            animateFromLastPercent: true,
            lineWidth: 20.0,
            progressColor: Colors.white,
            backgroundWidth: 50.0,
            center: Text(
              "00.00",
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 80.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

If you want your Pomodoro widget to take up the whole screen just wrap the container with an Expanded widget.

Comment: It didn't work. Thanks for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a revised tested and working code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Let's get productive!"),
        ),
        body: Material(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Pomodoro(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: 'Home',
             
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.analytics),
              label: 'Home',
             
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              label: 'Home',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Pomodoro extends StatelessWidget {
  const Pomodoro({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [Color(0xff1542bf), Color(0xff51a8ff)],
          begin: FractionalOffset(0.5, 1),
        ),
      ),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: Text(
              "Pomodoro",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 30.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20.0,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).